# How can I send data between 2 applications using SendMessage?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have 2 applications- Manager with this code:

```
procedure TForm1.CopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var sMsg: String;
begin
  if IsIconic(Application.Handle) then Application.Restore;
  sMsg := PWideChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);

  Caption := Caption+'#'+sMsg;

  Msg.Result := 123;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  WM_MY_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 1;
var
  h: HWND;
begin
  Caption := 'X';
  h := FindWindow('TForm1', 'Client');
  if not IsWindow(h) then Exit;

  Caption := Caption+'@';
  SendMessage(h, WM_MY_MESSAGE, 123, 321);
end;
```

And Client with:

```
procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
const
  WM_MY_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 1;
var DataStruct: CopyDataStruct;
    S: String;
    h: HWND;
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.Msg <> WM_MY_MESSAGE then Exit;


  h := FindWindow('TForm1', 'Manager');
  if not IsWindow(h) then Exit;

  Message.Result := 123;

  S := Edit2.Text + '@' + Edit1.Text;
  DataStruct.dwData := 0;
  DataStruct.cbData := 2*Length(S)+1;
  DataStruct.lpData := PWideChar(S);

  Caption := Caption + '#';

  PostMessage(h, WM_CopyData, Form1.handle, integer(@DataStruct));
end;
```

The code works- but only once.
Manager sends 2 integers: 123 and 321 as a "wake up" message to the Client.
Client responds by sending contents of Edit1 + Edit2.
Then Manager gets this data and shows on its caption.

Why does it work only once? After I click Button1 again it does nothing.

Comment: why won't u for example use  ready-made Chromis IPC lib instead of making your own ad hoc non-debugged one ?

Comment: Posting `WM_COPYDATA` (i.e. using PostMessage to send it) is not a good idea.

Comment: `WM_USER+1` is likely to collide with existing messages. If you need an application private message, use `WM_APP+x` instead.

Comment: what happens when u debug it? is the window sent? is it received ? trace both program step by step in those functions you show us and tell hwo the execution goes and which values are put into which variables on the first and on the second run - then we would compare it

Comment: `DataStruct.cbData := 2*Length(S)+1` - wrong, should be `DataStruct.cbData := 2*(Length(S)+1);`

Comment: @JonathanPotter why? also he cannot use SendMessage there, it would just create a deadlock to wait for SendMessage from inside another SendMessage

Comment: @Arioch'The:  You don't use `PostMessage` with `WM_COPYDATA`. Use `SendMessage` instead, which is stated both in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and in the [code example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The receiver should return `True` to indicate that the message was received (the posted code is wrong, as it returns `123`). After that, a `SendMessage` back is fine; the return of True would prevent any deadlock.

Comment: The reason for `SendMessage` is obvious - if you use `PostMessage` the pointer `@DataStruct` will point to a stack location that is invalid when the method returns (which, in this case, is immediately).

Comment: SendMessage always, WM_COPYDATA, and that's it

Comment: Thank you all. I changed to SendMessage, WM_APP+1 and 2*(Length(S)+1) and Message.Result := 1 and it works now.

Comment: @J... Windows could just copy the data - it anyway has to copy them acros processes... So, seems like some shaky implementation limitation.

Then IMHO he better to change his initiating WM_MY_MESSAGE  from SendMessage to PostMessage I bet. We can hope that WndProc (all the way from GDI to the VCL events) is re-entrable and would be called directly without queuing the message, but personally I'd prefer to lessen amount of assumptions.

Comment: Maybe also consider to user RegisterWindowsMessage API for the rendezvous rather than to rely on FindWindow with so generic names as 'TForm1' and 'client'

Comment: @Arioch - The OS would marshall the data when the target application retrieves WM_COPYDATA, before that how should it know to which process the data is to be marshalled? The source should be valid then, may not be the case with PostMessage. I don't see any implementation weakness.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz to make the copy of the data Windows does not need to know which process would receive it, knowing the source process initiated it would be enough, so copying could be done within the called PostMessage. I believe this implementation limitation comes from 16-bit times when all the program could be forced to run within 1 or maybe even 2 megabytes of RAM. Just no one seems to bother fixing this obsolete method

Comment: @Arioch - Why would PostMessage care what message it carries? You would call that a good design if it did? Besides, there's no guarantee that PostMessage will succeed, there's no point in looking at the message and taking specific action at post time.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz for the same reason SendMessage does - to make it work.

Comment: Accounting for different failures of PostMessage would indeed ask for extra coding though

Comment: @Arioch - SendMessage does not do anything. The OS marshals the data when the application retrieves WM_COPYDATA. With SendMessage this works, With PostMessage it may not work.

Comment: Marshalling data is exactly the special handling of a specitic message that you tell does not happen (or is it that SendMessage marchalls data for every message?). It really did not happen in Win16, there was no marchalling there indeed, but starting with WinNT there is

Comment: No, application does not "retrieve wm_copydata" unless the latter was Posted. Check thr code above, the application is forcefed with Wm_CopyData before it exits from SendMessage(wm_user+1)

Comment: @Arioch - Send/PostMessage does not care the message they carry. I can't know the exact implementation but you may have some insight after reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/16/10208976.aspx). One job of Get/PeekMessage is to dispatch sent messages, this can be considered retrieval of sent messages. At least that's what I meant.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz exactly says I think that Windows Manager when called via SendMessage (so, we may say SendMessage itself) does special handling (marshalling). And now, it is wrong to say that "Send Message dispatches" is the same as "application retrieves" since it swaps the object and the actor ,and our argument is exactly who does extra ad hoc handling, so who is the actor

Comment: Thank you for the link though, it describes a fundamental problem with the queue I did not thought about. Yes, making deterministic PostMessage(CopyData) is hardly possible. Anyway, WM_CopyData is but Win16 atavism, like WaveOut sound API and MCI video API

Comment: @Arioch - Ok, you seem to be right on both counts (SendMessage and sent message retrieval). It should perhaps is better to talk about "when the application receives the message".

Comment: @SertacAkyuz not even receive - it is easy to know when it receives: when GetMessage/PeekMessage functions return to the application. The fundamental problem is that PROCESSING of the message starts after RECEIVING of it ends. And Windows core can only know about the end of RECEIVING, not of PROCESSING. So freeing marshalling buffers could only be deterministically done before the processing starts, accounting for the processing would ask for the guesswork. Well, Protected Memory put natural limit of how far features of No-Protection era can be simulated

Comment: @Arioch No, that's not true GetMessage, PeekMessage etc will dispatch synchronous messages without returning.

Comment: @Arioch Also SendMessage does dispatch synchronous messages. That's one of its jobs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan depends of the idea behind "dispatch". If we consider the postal man putting some letter to your mailbox, that is definitely not what SendMessage does. If we consider something like DHL, knocking at yur door and putting a box to your ands - then yes, that is SendMessage. In this context the latter seems to be a bit more than Dispatch, it is also switching the control flow

Comment: @Arioch'The There's no debate about what dispatch means. It is a standard term. When you call `SendMessage`, `GetMessage`, `PeekMessage`, incoming synchronous messages are dispatched. The docs for `GetMessage`, for example, say: *The function dispatches incoming sent messages until a posted message is available for retrieval.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in comments, you must use `SendMessage` with `WM_COPYDATA`.  The primary reason for this is that the message sender is responsible for cleaning up the resources used for the transfer. As noted [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> The receiving application should consider the data read-only. The lParam parameter is valid only during the processing of the message. The receiving application should not free the memory referenced by lParam. If the receiving application must access the data after SendMessage returns, it must copy the data into a local buffer.

The only way this can work is if the message sender waits for the receiver to process the message and return a result.  Otherwise the sender cannot know when it is safe to release those resources.

`PostMessage` is asynchronous and returns immediately so this is simply not viable.  `SendMessage` will block until the receiver processes the message and assigns a return value.

Here you are passing a pointer to a stack allocated (local variable) record `@DataStruct`.  Further, you are also passing a pointer to a string which is a local variable.   If you use `PostMessage`, this method will return immediately - the stack locations (for value types like the record) will become invalid and susceptible to being overwritten.  The string lives on the heap but is reference counted and, in this case, will be freed when the method returns.

The solution is to always be sure to use `SendMessage` with `WM_COPYDATA`.